# Excel VBA: filter list for "empty" (failed matching) values then copy and paste to new column Code loop

Tags: excel, list, vba, loops, filter

I'm new to excel vba but basically what im trying to do is I compared two lists for common values.
There are some cells that appear empty but contain " " as the result of no match.
I am trying to loop through the list and only copy values that are not " " to a new column.
For some reason excel keeps looping without the code ever finishing unless I stop it.

```
Sub Order()

Dim x As Long
x = 2
ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 10).Select
While x < 19112 And ActiveCell.Value <> " "
ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 10).Select
ActiveCell.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 11).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Wend
x = x + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, before analysing the below code please have a look [How to avoid using .Select in Excel VBA Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Instead of looping which is rather slow you may want to try a faster solution using AutoFilter

```
Sub BetterOne()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim columnJ As Range
    Set columnJ = Range("J1:J" & lastRow)

    columnJ.AutoFilter
    columnJ.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    columnJ.Copy
    Range("K1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    columnJ.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I think I get whats going on. The criteria I need however will not be "<>". By that I meant anything which is not "" so how would you specify that.

Comment: I guess the other way around `=`